# HTML form disappears upon submission

Tags: php, html, forms, oracle

I am working on a project for school and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my html/php page.

For the record, I am making an html page with php and it is connected to an Oracle database.

I am trying to add a Person to the Person table but when I type in the information and click submit the form (the entire body of the page) completely disappears and the record is not added to the table.  I have been looking online all day for an answer and it still does not work.

My code:

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<a href="http://students.cs.ndsu.nodak.edu/~brfeist/trainStationSchedules.php"><font size="6">Schedules</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://students.cs.ndsu.nodak.edu/~brfeist/trainStationPassengers.php"><font size="6">Passengers</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://students.cs.ndsu.nodak.edu/~brfeist/trainStationAddPass.php"><font size="6">Add Passenger</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://students.cs.ndsu.nodak.edu/~brfeist/trainStationRemovePass.php"><font size="6">Remove Passenger</font></a><br>
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
<h1>Add Passenger</h1>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>

<?php
$passengerID = $passengerFName = $passengerLName = $carNo = $seatNo = $trainID = $tName = "";
$passengerIDErr = $passengerFNameErr = $passengerLNameErr = $carNoErr = $seatNoErr = $trainIDErr = $tNameErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["passengerFName"])) {
  $passengerFNameErr = "First Name is required";
 } else {
  $passengerFName = test_inpit($_POST["passengerFName"]);
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$passengerFName)) {
    $passengerFNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
   }
 }
 if (empty($_POST["passengerLName"])) {
  $passengerLNameErr = "Last Name is required";
 } else {
  $passengerLName = test_inpit($_POST["passengerLName"]);
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$passengerLName)) {
    $passengerLNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
   }
 }
 if (empty($_POST["carNo"])) {
  $carNoErr = "Car Number is required";
 } else {
  $carNo = test_inpit($_POST["carNo"]);
   if (!is_numeric($carNo)) {
    $carNoErr = "Only numbers allowed";
   }
 }
 if (empty($_POST["seatNo"])) {
  $seatNoErr = "Seat Number is required";
 } else {
  $seatNo = test_inpit($_POST["seatNo"]);
   if (!is_numeric($seatNo)) {
    $seatNoErr = "Only numbers allowed";
   }
 }
 if (empty($_POST["tName"])) {
  $tNameErr = "Train Name is required";
 } else {
  $tName = test_inpit($_POST["tName"]);
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$tName)) {
    $tNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
   }
 }
 $passengerID = test_input($_POST["passengerID"]);
  if (!is_numeric($passengerID)) {
   $passengerIDErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
 }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Enter all information for the passenger<br>
<b>First Name:</b> <input type="text" name="passengerFName" value="<?php echo $passengerFName;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $passengerFNameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<b>Last Name:</b> <input type="text" name="passengerLName" value="<?php echo $passengerLName;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $passengerLNameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<b>Car Number:</b> <input type="text" name="carNo" value="<?php echo $carNo;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $carNoErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<b>Seat Number:</b> <input type="text" name="seatNo" value="<?php echo $seatNo"?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $seatNoErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<b>Train Name:</b> <input type="text" name="tName" value="<?php echo $tName"?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $tNameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit">

<br><br><br>

<?php

$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=db1.chpc.ndsu.nodak.edu)(Port=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=cs)))');
$query = 'SELECT MAX(personID)
   FROM Person';

$stid = oci_parse($conn,$query);
oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);

//iterate through each row
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC))
{
 //iterate through each item in the row and echo it
 foreach ($row as $item)
 {
  $passengerID = $item + 1;
 }
}
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>

<?php

$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=db1.chpc.ndsu.nodak.edu)(Port=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=cs)))');
$query = 'SELECT trainID
   FROM Train
   WHERE tName = \''. $tName. '\'';

$stid = oci_parse($conn,$query);
$c1 = oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);

if ($c1 === FALSE) {
 Echo "Error! Train name does not exist";
}

//iterate through each row
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC))
{
 //iterate through each item in the row and echo it
 foreach ($row as $item)
 {
  $trainID = $item;
 }
}
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>

<?php

$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=db1.chpc.ndsu.nodak.edu)(Port=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=cs)))');
$query = 'INSERT INTO Person (personID, fname, lname, carNo, seatNo, trainID)
   VALUES (\''. $passengerID. '\', \''. $passengerFName. '\', \''. $passengerLName. '\', \''. $carNo. '\', \''. $seatNo. '\', \''. $trainID. '\')';

$stid = oci_parse($conn,$query);
$c2 = oci_execute($stid,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

if ($c2 === FALSE) {
 Echo "Error! Record was not added. Please check the information and try again";
}
elseif ($c2 === TRUE) {
 Echo "Success! Passenger was added to the system";
}

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any errors that might stop the script when you load it the second time (=when submitting the form)? is the `action="<?php echo
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` ok, so do you send the form to the correct, same script?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors that I know of.  I have been using the <!-- action=<?php echo htmmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" --> for all of my other pages and it works.  This is the only page not working.

Comment: As a note, the incorrect placement of double quotes in the form section have been corrected. Still disappearing.

Comment: I can't spell, I'm dumb.  Sorry.